# pandas dataframe groupby add second level index (integer) based on position in group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with time values and group values as columns index by a running index for the time value.
I want to group by the coup column and add a second level integer index given the position in each group
Example Data Frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.array([np.random.randint(0,10,20), np.arange(0,20,1) ])
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'group': data[0, :], 'time': data[1, :]})
dataset.index.name = 'global index'
dataset.sort_values(['group', 'global index'], axis=0)
```

Now, I have no clue on how to add a second level index without iterating over each group with a for loop and index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you wnat this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(123)
data = np.array([np.random.randint(0,10,20), np.arange(0,20,1) ])
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'group': data[0, :], 'time': data[1, :]})
dataset.index.name = 'global index'
dataset = dataset.sort_values(['group', 'global index'], axis=0)
dataset = dataset.set_index((dataset.groupby('group').cumcount()).rename('2nd Index'), append=True)
dataset
```

Output:

```
                        group  time
global index 2nd Index             
8            0              0     8
11           1              0    11
12           2              0    12
16           3              0    16
17           4              0    17
3            0              1     3
7            1              1     7
9            2              1     9
19           3              1    19
0            0              2     0
1            1              2     1
4            0              3     4
14           1              3    14
15           0              4    15
18           1              4    18
2            0              6     2
6            1              6     6
5            0              9     5
10           1              9    10
13           2              9    13
```

Comment: `dataset.set_index((dataset.groupby('group').cumcount()).rename('2nd Index'), append=True)` like ths to start with 0 but yes exactly like you proposed thanks !

Comment: @MadMax Great. I am glad I could help.  Happy coding!

Comment: the main problem is that it is very slow, since it iterates over each row I guess

Comment: Actually, this is a vectorized solution, It is not interating over each row.  It is doing a cumcount for the number of rows in each group.

Comment: hm than I have to check why it is so slow, and crashes my Jupiter kernel on a larger dataset (180 groups and 60k rows)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.array([np.random.randint(0,10,20), np.arange(0,20,1) ])
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'group': data[0, :], 'time': data[1, :]})
dataset['global index'] = dataset.index
dataset.set_index(['group', 'global index']).sort_values(['group', 'global index'])
```

Comment: no sadly it does not because global index is already an index and not a column